# javascript object nested callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm designing an object as follows. But JavaScript does not nested callable. I thank colleagues an idea about it. I share the original code.

```
var preloading = {};
Object.defineProperties(preloading,{
    show:{
        enumarable:true,
        writable:false,
        value:function(value){
            var $this = this;
            jQuery($this._object).find('.text').eq(0).html($this.text).end().end()
                .velocity('stop').velocity('fadeIn',{
                    duration:500,
                    complete:function(){
                        console.log('preloading show');
                        if(value instanceof Function || typeof value === 'function'){
                            $this._start(value);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    },
    hide:{
        enumarable:true,
        writable:false,
        value:function(value){
            var $this = this;
            jQuery($this._object).velocity('stop').velocity('fadeOut',{
                duration:500,
                complete:function(){
                    console.log('preloading hide');
                    if(value instanceof Function || typeof value === 'function'){
                        $this._finish(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
    _start:{
        enumerable:false,
        writable:false,
        value:function(value){
            var $this = this;
            value.call(undefined, $this);
        }
    },
    _finish:{
        enumerable:false,
        writable:false,
        value:function(value){
            var $this = this;
            value.call(undefined, $this)
        }
    },
    _object:{
        writable:true,
        value:'#preloader2',
        enumarable:false
    },
    object:{
        get:function(){
            return this._object;
        },
        set:function(value){
            this._object = value;
        }
    },
    _text:{
        writable:true,
        value:'yükleniyor..',
        enumerable:false
    },
    text:{
        get:function(){
            return this._text;
        },
        set:function(value){
            this._text = value;
        }
    }
});
```

then i try

```
preloading.show(function(preloading){preloading.hide()})
```

--first callback starting

```
//show callback starting
```

--second callback not starting

an idea?

Comment: `enumarable` should be `enumerable`

Comment: it does not matter. I wrote by hand quickly

Comment: Of course it does not matter, that's why this is a comment not an answer :-)

Comment: i edited. But not working :)

Comment: Just a question, isn't it `Object.defineProperties(...`?

Comment: I share the original code. But not working...

Comment: What is not working? Please tell us what exceptions you are getting. Also, why are you calling your callbacks with `new`?

Answer (score 2):

You've got different variable names - your parameter is `callback`, but you're calling `value`.

Also you've misspelled `Object.defineProperties` (`preloading.defineProperties`), `enumerable` (`enumarable`) and `setTimeout`(`setTimeOut`).

And of course you're calling `preloading.hide()` without a callback, so it tries to invoke `.call` on `undefined` which throws as well.

You'll want to read [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988363/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var preloading = {};
Object.defineProperties(preloading,{
    show:{
        enumerable:true,
        writable:false,
        value:function(callback){
            var $this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('show callback starting');
                callback.call(undefined, $this);
            },500)
        }
    },
    hide:{
      enumerable:true,
      writable:false,
      value:function(callback){
          var $this = this;
          setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('hide callback starting');
              callback.call(undefined, $this);
          },500)
      }
    }
});
```

You used `preloading.defineProperties(....);` instead of `Object.defineProperties(....);` and `setTimeOut` instead of `setTimeout` that might be the problem.